# Merging two objects in JS and select multiple values based on single input

Tags: javascript, image, object

**PROBLEM:**

I wish to merge two objects together and select multiple values based on an integer input. More specifically, I want to assign image source and alt-title to a `<img>` element based on an integer input.

**CODE:**

**JS object #1**

```
const sources = {
  1: "assets/images/newyorktimes.png",
  2: "assets/images/cnn.png",
  3: "assets/images/bbc.png",
  4: "assets/images/washingtonpost.png"
};
```

**JS object #2**

```
const sourcenames = {
  1: "New York Times",
  2: "CNN",
  3: "BBC",
  4: "Washington Post"
};
```

**INPUT VALUE:**

I get the input value from a parameter, which I deconstruct in the following way:

```
const { 
  fictionsource: fictionSrc,  // INPUT HERE (e.g., 1)
  content: contentSrc         // CONTENT HERE
} = stimulus;
```

I assign content in the following way:

```
const newsContent = node.querySelector(".js-news-content");
newsContent.innerHTML = contentSrc;
```

Now, I wish to assign image source and alt-text based on the input value. For instance, if the value is 1, then I wish the following to happen:

```
const newsImage = node.querySelector(".js-news-image img");
// Assign assets/images/newyorktimes.png to src-attribute
// Assign New York Times to alt-attribute
```

**DESIRED OUTPUT:**

The recommended approach to combine the two objects and to assign image source and alt-text based on input value.

Comment: Objects do not have numerical keys, are you sure you don't have an array?

Comment: @HereticMonkey Then it is possible I have written the code wrong, how would I transform the values into an array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need something like this:

```
// In principle is better to have 
// empty objects.
const sources = Object.assign(Object.create(null),{
  1: "assets/images/newyorktimes.png",
  2: "assets/images/cnn.png",
  3: "assets/images/bbc.png",
  4: "assets/images/washingtonpost.png"
});

const sourcenames = Object.assign(Object.create(null),{
  1: "New York Times",
  2: "CNN",
  3: "BBC",
  4: "Washington Post"
});

// Here we hardcode 
// the case when fictionsource 
// is equal to 1. 
const stimulus = {
  fictionsource: 1,
  content: "<div>test</div>"
}

const { 
  fictionsource: fictionSrc,  // INPUT HERE (e.g., 1)
  content: contentSrc         // CONTENT HERE
} = stimulus;


const newsImage = node.querySelector(".js-news-image img");

if (newsImage && typeof sources[fictionSrc] !== 'undefined' && typeof sourcenames[fictionSrc] !== undefined) {
   newsImage.setAttribute("src", sources[fictionSrc]);
   newsImage.setAttribute("alt", sourcenames[fictionSrc]);
} else {
    throw new Error("Incorrect data");
}
```

This is how you can "merge" the objects in one:

```
const sources = {
  1: "assets/images/newyorktimes.png",
  2: "assets/images/cnn.png",
  3: "assets/images/bbc.png",
  4: "assets/images/washingtonpost.png"
};

const sourcenames = {
  1: "New York Times",
  2: "CNN",
  3: "BBC",
  4: "Washington Post"
};

const result = {}

Object.keys(sources).forEach((x) => {
    result[sources[x]] = sourcenames[x];
});

console.log(result);
```

And one idea better:

```
const sources = {
  1: "assets/images/newyorktimes.png",
  2: "assets/images/cnn.png",
  3: "assets/images/bbc.png",
  4: "assets/images/washingtonpost.png"
};

const sourcenames = {
  1: "New York Times",
  2: "CNN",
  3: "BBC",
  4: "Washington Post"
};

const result = Object.keys(sources).reduce((acc, value) => {
    acc[sources[value]] = sourcenames[value];
    return acc;
},Object.create(null));

console.log(result);
```

In case you want to keep the indexes and have nested objects check this example:

```
const sources = Object.assign(Object.create(null), {
    1: "assets/images/newyorktimes.png",
    2: "assets/images/cnn.png",
    3: "assets/images/bbc.png",
    4: "assets/images/washingtonpost.png"
});

const sourcenames = Object.assign(Object.create(null),{
    1: "New York Times",
    2: "CNN",
    3: "BBC",
    4: "Washington Post"
});

const result = Object.keys(sources).
filter((key) => typeof sourcenames[key] !== 'undefined').
reduce((acc, value) => {
    acc[value] = Object.assign(Object.create(null), {
        source: sources[value],
        sourcename: sourcenames[value]
    });
    return acc;
},Object.create(null));

console.log(result);
```

Edit: If you use array instead object the cons is in a bit slow access 
to elements. You will need to search in the array for according element. This is in case if you don't have array indexes.

Comment: Is there a way to combine the key/value pairs into one object or array?

Comment: Yes. Check the second example which I just did.

Answer (score 0):

You could loop through your objects like this :

```
let source = null
for(var key in sources){
     if ( value == key ) // value is the number you are looking for
           sources = sources.key
}
newsImage.src = source
```

But it would be easyer if your objects were array, then you could access it directly :

```
sources = ["assets/images/newyorktimes.png", "assets/images/cnn.png", "assets/images/bbc.png", "assets/images/washingtonpost.png" ]
newsImage.src = sources[value]
```

Hope this help !